# Cookie Not Saving To Another url with the same domain

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, cookies, spring-boot

This is the sample code of my project.
I created an `ajax` function on my `html` file that will go to **api_base_url/login?id=P1003**

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
 $.ajax({
    url : api_base_url + "/login",
    type : "GET",
    data : {id: "P1003"},
    success : function (response){
        if(response != null) {
            window.open(api_base_url + response);
                }
            }
  });
})
```

In my controller there is a `GetMapping` function for "/login" that will create cookies on the domain and will return a string URL on where he is going to redirect next.

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value = "id", defaultValue = "*") String id){

 Cookie SESSION_ID = new Cookie("SESSION_ID", id);
 SESSION_ID.setPath("/");
 response.addCookie(SESSION_ID);
 return "/home";
}
```

Now I also have a controller for "/home" to get the cookies I set in the browser.

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ParseException {

     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
     mav.setViewName("home");
     Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
     JSONObject ses = new JSONObject();

     System.out.println("Cookies " + ses);

     return mav;

    }
```

"/home" controller can't seem to find the cookies I set in the "/login" controller though they have the same domain.
Whenever I go to **api_base_url/home**, the cookies are empty
I have to visit the **api_base_url/login?id=P1003** first before **api_base_url/home** can have the cookies that I needed.

pls help I am stuck T_x

Comment: have you tried using @CookieValue("SESSION_ID ") String value in the handler method, double check the network tab of the browser whether cookie has been sent as part of the request. Possibly share the Network request

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's where I am checking the cookies, in the network tab. When the page redirects to "home", the cookies are empty. I still have to go to the first url my ajax called which is the login.

Comment: I tried using the CookieValue as parameter but it is still giving me an error since it cannot detect the cookie that I set 2017-08-15 13:14:05.049  WARN 8540 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException: Missing cookie 'SESSION_ID_J ' for method parameter of type String

Comment: But your cookie is 'SESSION_ID' not 'SESSION_ID_J'

Comment: oh that, I just change the name of the session on my project. But the error I received have the same concept